# PHP MySQL Get data between dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple code that I can't get to work. I'm trying to get all the data between selected dates but it isn't working. Here are my codes:

**form**

```
 <form action="selectedInvoices.php" method="POST">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <label>From
        <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="from" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <label>To
        <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="to" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <button class="button" type="submit">Show Invoice</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

**selectedInvoices.php**

```
$fromOrig = strtotime($_POST['from']);
$toOrig = strtotime($_POST['to']);

$from = date('Y-m-d', $fromOrig);
$to = date('Y-m-d', $toOrig);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM allinvoices WHERE acc_date BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."'");
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
$drno = $r['drno'];
$name = $r['name'];
$amount = $r['amountdue'];
```

The data type of my `acc_date` field is varchar which I guess is wrong here. The format of the date when I insert is m-d-Y.

What should I do to make the code work? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: "The data type of my acc_date field is varchar which I guess is wrong here." Well thats itself is wrong there. how then to compare date ?

Comment: @Plum is there a way that I can keep the data type and do the conversion in my code?

Comment: WHERE `STR_TO_DATE(acc_date, 'Y-m-D')` Change the format to what you need.

Comment: @Mihai so I do not need to do the strtotime function anymore?

Comment: From your comments, I'm assuming the date in acc_date in stored in 'm-d-Y' format.  So in that case add this to your SQL: WHERE STR_TO_DATE(acc_date, '%m-%d-%Y')

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/791b6/1 i'm not getting anything here

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/791b6/3 i tried like this also

Comment: @Mihai I'm not getting any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(acc_date, '%Y/%m/%d')  BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."'
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/791b6/12)

Date in mysql is Y-m-d,you were comparing with d-m-Y for BETWEEN.Also make sure $from is < than $to.

Comment: With my code above, should I just change my query with your code?

Comment: @FewFlyBy If this doesnt work vardump $from and $to and edit your question with the results.

Comment: Hey btw, the dates in my database is Y/m/d

Comment: This is the exact code I need. Thank you very much, sir!

Answer (score 1):

Since you said your date format in the database is `m-d-Y`, you could simply change your `$to`and `$from` to the appropriate format.

Replace

```
$from = date('Y-m-d', $fromOrig);
$to = date('Y-m-d', $toOrig);
```

With

```
$from = date('m-d-Y', $fromOrig);
$to = date('m-d-Y', $toOrig);
```

And for your query, you can replace the `BETWEEN` with

```
acc_date >= $from && acc_date <= $to
```

Comment: I still get empty data

Answer (score 1):

I recently worked on something similar.

I used the less than and more than operators, so

```
... WHERE startDate > $date AND endDate < $date
```

Also ensure that your date fields in the DB are actually proper `date` type fields. Make sure that when you insert a date, it's formatted correctly( IE. `date` type may be `yyyy-mm-dd`.) Otherwise the DB won't read it correctly.

And just a side note, you can do away with the concatenation in your query by changing the surrounding quotes to single (the quotes around the whole query)

```
 BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."'");
```

can become

```
BETWEEN $from AND $to');
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort!